# Updating a phone number in the Exchange GAL using Powershell

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, exchange

How do I use powershell to update the Exchange GAL with "Business Phone" and Location?  I don't see them in "get-mailbox"

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually my own previous post wouldn't have worked. this works (and doesn't require 3rd party products):

```
$user = get-aduser jdoe
Set-ADObject $user -Replace @{telephoneNumber=12345}
```

Comment: I get the error `'get-adobject' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet` .. I think I need to load a runspace.  Do you know what that is?

Comment: yes, you need to install AD RSAT tools. and be sure to include the Powershell cmdlets. First you download RSAT from the web, then you have to turn on those Features in Add Windows Features. THEN open powershell and run import-module active*. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

A room mailbox has an associated user that sets these properties.  Using the Quest AD cmdlets, available [here](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx), you could run the following -

```
Set-QADUser -Identity $RoomMailboxUser -Office "Location here" -PhoneNumber "Phone number here"
```